# How to handle gmail compose button? I'm trying to find the element by xpath, cssSelector... etc. but not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I just want to click on compose button after login to the gmail account.
When I am trying to find the element by xpath(Static, dynamic and customized way), cssSelector. It will not able to find the element I don't know why?
Can any one suggest me how to face this challenge?

```
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\":f3\"]/div/div")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div")).click();    
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3']")).click();
```

```
public class ComposeMail  extends GmailTest{

    WebDriver driver;
    public void getLogin()
    {
        GmailTest gm=new GmailTest();
        gm.setUp();
        gm.gmailLogin();

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3']")).click();
    }
```

FAILED: composeMail
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your xpath, but consider this one for better longevity: `//*[contains(text(),"Compose")]`

Things I'd do in your situation:

1. Put a break point on the `driver.findElement` line and debug your script. When execution halts at the break point, look at the chromedriver window -- do you see the Compose button in the DOM?
2. Consider an alternative route -- Gmail has hotkeys for actions; the hotkey for composing a new message is `c`. So you could try the `sendKeys` method on a different element (like `//body`).